# File Input Control with Rails 4, Bootstrap 4 Alpha, Paperclip and Simple Form Does Not Display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, simple-form

I've been playing around with Bootstrap 4 Alpha2 (using the bootstrap_rubygem), Rails, Paperclip and Simple_Form and so far almost everything is working pretty great with one exception, and that is file inputs.

When I have a file input, the label shows up fine; however, the actual control for browsing the file appears to be hidden (tested in Safari, Chrome, nor Firefox).

[image: Notice the missing form control]

Oddly enough, tooltips pop up when I hover over the area where the control should be.

[image: Tooltip showing that no file is selected]

And the control actually functions and I am able to select a file. When I do, again the input area is blank, but I can hover and see the file name and the file is successfully saved when I hit create.

[image: File name is now displayed as a tooltip]

So really, everything is working except the user experience is pretty frustrating and I can't figure out what I need to change to get the file input to show up correctly.

Here is the form view:

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for(@sample) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :url, class: "form-control", placeholder: "http://www.example.com", error: "You must include the http part of the web address." %>
  </div><!-- ./form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">  
    <%= f.input :logo %>
  </div><!-- ./form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is an extract from an updated Bootstrap initializer for simple_form that I updated for match the latest stypes in Bootstrap 4:

*simple_form_bootstrap.rb*

```
config.wrappers :vertical_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
b.use :html5
b.use :placeholder
b.optional :maxlength
b.optional :readonly
b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

b.use :input, class: 'form-control-file'
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'form-control-error' }
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'text-muted' }
end
```

And when I view source, here is what is spit out for the form (with the security stuff removed):

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_sample" id="new_sample" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/sample" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group string required sample_name">
            <label class="string required control-label" for="sample_name">
            <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
                Name
            </label>
            <input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="sample[name]" id="sample_name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group url optional sample_url">
            <label class="url optional control-label" for="sample_url">
                Url
            </label>
            <input class="string url optional form-control" placeholder="http://www.example.com" type="url" name="sample[url]" id="sample_url" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- ./form-group -->


    <div class="form-group file optional sample_logo">
        <label class="file optional control-label" for="sample_logo">
            Logo
        </label>
        <input class="file optional form-control-file" type="file" name="sample[logo]" id="sample_logo" />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And just for kicks, here are the relevant gems from the gem file:

*Gemfile.rb*

```
gem "bootstrap", "~> 4.0.0.alpha2"
gem "simple_form"
gem "country_select"
source "https://rails-assets.org" do
  gem "rails-assets-tether", ">= 1.1.0"
end
gem "paperclip", "~>3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

Did I make a simple typo error, or is there some other simple_form internal thing I need to adjust?

Thanks!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857788/how-to-remove-default-input-class-type-from-simple-form-using-rails-4-and-boots#_=_

Answer (score 0):

default simple form add data type of input into the form group and also the field and label

one way to work around this issue is by setting these scss:

```
.simple_form {
    .file {
        display: inherit;
        input {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    .form-group.file {
        display: inherit;
    }
}
```

Comment: For another solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857788/how-to-remove-default-input-class-type-from-simple-form-using-rails-4-and-boots#_=_